# Why cant copy elision take place when a 'by-value' parameter is also the 'by-value' return argument?

Tags: c++, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

In the following code snippet my function tries to return it's 'by-value' argument as a 'by-value' return-value. I watched a video where it stated: "It is physically not possible to do copy elision here.." but I dont see why the we couldn't use the same memory address for the function parameter as well as the return value.

```
std::string foo(std::string s){
    return s;
}
```

I tried to understand it by watching a video but can't see where this would fail to do copy elision.

Comment: It's hard to pull off if the function body is unavailable. For [N]RVO, the object needs to be constructed directly at the desired adddress. So if you did `std::string a = foo("42");`, the caller would need to somehow ask the function before calling it if it's going to return the same object you give it or not (so the caller could directly construct `a` from `"42"`), and I don't think there's an estabilished way of doing that. But I don't see why it wouldn't be possible in theory.

Comment: parameter "construction" is done by the caller, while return "construction" is done by the callee, the caller can't know that it doesn't need to allocate the parameter because it is going to be returned, but the compiler should just move the one allocated by the caller into the return slot, ie: a simple memcpy, that's assuming the function doesn't get inlined by the compiler.

Comment: With a usual default calling convention, `std::string s` is constructed and destroyed by a caller, and it can't know if `s` is returned and must not be destroyed.

Comment: I get that the parameter is a local variable in the caller scope and hence in the stack frame of the caller function on a lower memory address than the base pointer of the caller function. When I call another function again the local variables and the return value have different memory addresses (above and below the basepointer) but these addresses should just hold other memory addresses that point to where the actual content of the variables lie and couldnt these addresses all be the same?

Comment: That could happen, but then you will be using python or java which have reference semantics only, and the end result is equivalent to a c++ move which the compiler will do anyway, so that's already done.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of who is in charge of destroying function arguments, they cannot also be the result object created at the call site.
This is required by C++17, and would be difficult/impossible to implement with NRVO<sup>(1)</sup> for function parameters.
Consider this function and call:

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string s);

std::string r = foo("...");
```

What happens is:

1. a `std::string s` argument is constructed from `"..."`
2. control is transferred into the function, and the function does its work
3. in an implementation-defined order<sup>(2)</sup>:

   - control is transferred back to the caller
   - the function argument is destroyed by whoever has control

If the **caller** is in charge of destroying `s`, how is the caller supposed to know that `r` is the same object as `s`? It's impossible to know without looking inside the definition of `foo`, or it would need to get additional run-time information that informs it about which parameter (if any) is the same object as the result object.

If the **callee** is in charge of destroying `s`, that would mean that `r` cannot be `s` because `s` is destroyed by `foo`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> NRVO means Named Return Value Optimization.

<sup>(2)</sup>
The relevant wording for step 3 is in [[expr.call] p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6):

> It is
> implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.
> The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the full-expression where the function call appears.